# Can I Overwrite **Mapper.xml On My Applications?

Tags: mybatis

When I use Mybatis 3.4.2 and spring boot。

I found that when I write ****Mapper.xml** on my business jars, But Others want to overwrite my ****Mapper.xml** on there spring boot applications, but they can't do it With *org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.mappedStatements* use **StrictMap**, Con't
overwrite value for special key.

So I what know is there other goal for this design.

Comment: Why would you do that? The mapper represents a set of SQL statements carefully manufactured for performance and speed. I doubt you'll produce better SQL at runtime.

Comment: Because in the process of product implementation, sometimes need to expand the table field, then need to do the second development of the product without affecting the JAR package, our general practice is to reserve the field, but this leads to the table field name is not enough to know the meaning.